# where (if at all) are incident event logs stored on BMC Remedy 7.1?

Tags: remedy

I am hoping to apply process mining to our Incident data. Is there a table / view where Remedy would store raw event data? The data I am looking for would be in the format of incident number, timestamp, and action taken on a ticket (ie. submitted, assigned to A, marked as resolved, etc).

The closest I was able to come to this data was via ODBC from HPD_HelpDeskAssignmentLogJoin. Unfortunately, there are no time stamps here, and seems the data is fairly limited in general.

Could I please ask you where I would be able to find raw event data?

If any one could please shed some light on this that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I missed that but seems that much of the information I am looking for can be found here: HPD:HelpDesk_AuditLogSystem.